# While Using Blender 2.93 with Mac Control C works like Command C

Tags: animation

While Using Blender 2.93 with MacBook, Control C works like Command C.
I can not copy location and rotation of an object to an other object.

This is frustrating

Answer (score 1):

Ok Standard Blender :)

1st goto preferences.
2nd Click AddOns.
3rd Click Copy Attributes.

Then you can use Control C

Thanks to the https://youtu.be/f7zF1pjpc74